# jQuery AJAX not working using IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

I have seen lots of other people with this problem all over SO and elsewhere but none of the given solutions seem to work for me.

I have a jQuery AJAX call to an ASHX handler.  The code works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE (versions 8, 9 or 10).

It looks like so (simplified):

```
var val = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Source/Handlers/Search.ashx?q=' + val,
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(w,t,f) {
         alert(w + "\n" + t + "\n" + f);
    },
    success: function (data) {
         ...
    }
 });
```

When I run the code in IE the error handler kicks in and says

```
[object Object]
error
error
```

Useful huh?

The ASHX handler is like this (again it is simplified):

```
public class Search : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Buffer = false;

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Suggestions> jsonResponse = new List<Suggestions>();

        // do some stuff

        context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(jsonResponse));
    }
}
```

I have tried swapping "GET" for "POST", I have tried enabling and disabling the "cache" property, I have tried different dataType settings such as "json", "xml" and "text".

Using HTTP Fiddler I can see that the json response does come back but IE doesn't seem to be able to process it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is the JSON response in TextView from HTTP Fiddler:

```
543
[{"title":"GAMES","results":[{"title":"abcdefg™","link":"http://www.abcdefg.com/en_gb/abcdefg/","image":"/uploadedImages/abcdefg/games/1-Game_Folder_Master(1)/Config/abcdefg(1).jpg","total":""},{"title":"abcdefg","link":"http://www.abcdefg.com/en_gb/abcdefg","image":"/uploadedImages/abcdefg/games/1-Game_Folder_Master(1)/Config/abcdefg.jpg","total":""},{"title":"abcdefgg","link":"/Retailers/?game=1432&amp;platform=0","image":"/uploadedImages/abcdefg/games/1-Game_Folder_Master(1)/Config/abcdefg.jpg?n=9736","total":""},{"title":"abcdefg","link":"http://www.abcdefg.com","image":"/uploadedImages/abcdefg/games/1-Game_Folder_Master(1)/Config/abcdefg.jpg","total":""},{"title":"abcdefg","link":"/Retailers/?game=1763&amp;platform=0","image":"/uploadedImages/abcdefg/games/1-Game_Folder_Master(1)/Config/abcdefg_promo.jpg","total":""}],"total":"24","link":"/Search/?q=total"},{"title":"MEDIA","results":[{"title":"Videos","link":"/Search/?q=total","image":"","total":"1"},{"title":"Screenshots","link":"/Search/?q=total","image":"","total":"35"}],"total":null,"link":null}]
0
```

**EDIT 2**

Hmmm, I updated the $.ajax call to alert w.status and it returned "404". Confused - how can it return 404 in the status when Fiddler shows the response as 200?

Comment: Can you post the JSON response?

Comment: Why are you using alert? Use the console!

Comment: Yes if you could tell us what are you getting from the url if you hit that directly in the browser? Is it producing a valid json response?

Comment: True! I should do that, the error is useless anyway...

Comment: +1 to @epascarello. Use `console.dir()` instead of `alert()`, and you'll get much more useful information out of `w`, `f` and `t`.

Comment: @Spudley I think "much more useful" might be an overstatement. `t` and `f` are just strings, so there's no real difference between what you'll see using `console.dir()` or `alert()`. The only one that will be different is `w`, and the jqXhr object might not have anything useful to solve the issue in it anyway.

Comment: Edited post to include JSON response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found the problem. When using IE I need to call JSON.parse(data) on the data object that is returned back from my ASHX handler.  To do this, use a non-jQuery method of calling Ajax.  It has meant that I have two different blocks of Javascript - one for IE and one for other browsers.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", "/Source/Handlers/Search.ashx?q=" + val + "&d=" + dateObj.getTime(), false);
    xhReq.send(null);
    AjaxSuccess(xhReq.responseText);
} else {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Source/Handlers/Search.ashx',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { q: val },
        contentType: "application/json;",
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            ...
        }
    });
 }

 function AjaxSuccess(data) {
     data = JSON.parse(data);
     ...
 }
```

Strangely, the JSON.parse() method throws an "unexpected character" error in Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember a problem like this.
Could you try adding

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

to the ajax request properties. I think that solved the problems back then.

Comment: +1. I would have given a similar answer if you hadn't beaten me to it.

Comment: It didn't work for me unfortunately. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `data : {q : val}` and see if this solves the issue:

```
 var val = $(this).val();

 $.ajax({
    url: '/Source/Handlers/Search.ashx',
    type: "GET",
    data : {q : val},  //<--------send it this way
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(w,t,f) {
       alert(w + "\n" + t + "\n" + f);
    },
    success: function (data) {
       ...
    }
 });
```

Comment: Is this just a guess or is there a reason you think IE would be fine with this but struggle with the query string being part of the URL?

Comment: Frankly speaking never faced an issue like this before but yeah i would say this is a guess.

Comment: @rf_wilson  if you could tell us what are you getting from the url if you hit that directly in the browser? Is it producing a valid json response?

Comment: See original post above, JSON response added

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with encoding. try this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: encodeURI(url ),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
                            result = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data))
                                                }
       });
```